# How to count duplicates based on group by as well as see if values are present in the same field values?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I  have a table that contains ~1mil rows that looks like so

```
GROUP  |  ID  

A        AED12
A        6D04K
A        AED12 
B        VFR54
B        VFR54
B        9KMN2
B        AED12 
C        9KMN2
C        9KMN2
C        VFR54
```

I would like to have an output that counts the number of duplicates that is grouped by 'GROUP' WHILE also seeing which 'IDs' are present across multiple groups (reference 'AED12' that is in both GROUP A and B).

I am using this query for first question of duplicates across each group

```
select GROUP, ID, count(ID)
from TABLE1
group by GROUP, ID
having count(ID) > 1
;
```

output of query above

```
GROUP  |  ID   | COUNT

A        AED12     2
B        VFR54     2
C        9KMN2     2
```

I would like to sum the number of duplicates per group (how many dups are in Group A, B, etc.) which would like so (made up #s for example purposes)

```
GROUP | Sum of Dups IDs
A         2134
B         23321
C         11235
```

While also identifying which IDs are present in more than one group and count how many are present across the groups. Output would be something like a case when field that says is ID present in more than 1 group, if so 'true', if not - 'false'. Still thinking about how to count/group what the output would look like since there  are million plus rows..

Any help would be much appreciated - new to Snowflake.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the results you want.

Comment: I edited the question - thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of different groups an id appears in using window functions and then aggregate.  Here is an example counting singletons and pairs:

```
select group,
       count(*) as num_elements,
       count_if(num_groups = 1) as num_onesies,
       count_if(num_groups = 2) as num_twosies
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as num_groups
      from table1 t
     ) t
group by group;
```

EDIT:

If you have duplicates, it is probably best to remove them before doing the above processing:

```
select group,
       count(*) as num_elements,
       count_if(num_groups = 1) as num_onesies,
       count_if(num_groups = 2) as num_twosies
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as num_groups
      from (select distinct group, id
            from table1 t
           ) t
     ) t
group by group
```

Comment: @Gordan Linoff! Thank you - so is this essentially taking each group and seeing if IDs are present in more than one of them? Is that the num_onsies, num_twosites are?

Comment: @Dinho . . . Yes.  "Onesies" and "twosies" are colloquial terms in English, most commonly used for bathing suits and infant clothes -- referring to the number of pieces of clothing in an outfit.

Comment: Figured lol just making sure I understood the syntax. So if num_groups = 1 -- that means those IDs are unique across each group, but if num_groups = 2 -- then those IDs are seen in other groups?

Comment: @Dinho . . . "2" means exactly two other groups.  "3" would be 3 other groups, and so on.  You can use `>= 2` for two or more groups.

Comment: I see - I guess I am confused on my results then - because I am getting values that are unique to a single group but still showing up in '>2' groups field. Is that something on my end with the data? Is there a way to count which ids are paired to which groups?

Comment: @Dino . . . Do you have duplicates in the data?  The above is counting the number of rows in the table -- so it assumes unique groups.  Oh, I see, you do have duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! I should have caught that initially..Appreciate your help!